# How to configure the height of 'Insert Character' popup window in OOTB Tridion?

Tags: 2011, configuration, cme

RTF Field --> Insert special character.

We have added few more special characters to the list.

We have a requirement to increase the height of the popup window.Where can we configure it ?

Comment: Which Tridion version are you using?

Comment: SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1

Answer (score 7):

It should be possible to write a GUI extension which adds a bit of javascript in the special charather dialog and cause it to resize the height a little more.

Albert has a great blog post to explain how to slot in your javascript code:

http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/

Answer (score 6):

The size of that popup window is unfortunately not configurable.